# Why does `v.names` help `reshape()` guess time-varying variables when melting data?

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following `data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(client = 1:2, Month1 = rnorm(2), Month2 = rnorm(2))
> dt
   client     Month1     Month2
1:      1 -0.1348442  0.6787494
2:      2  0.8431479 -1.3760579
```

I'm trying to melt `dt` using reshape()` to make it look like this:

```
client  time       value
     1     1  -0.1348442
     1     2   0.6787494
     2     1   0.8431479 
     2     2  -1.3760579
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045405/reshape-data-in-r-when-reshape-cannot-guess-the-names-of-the-time-varying-variab) to get something very similar. However, I really dont understand the syntax.

```
> reshape(dt, varying = 2:3, v.names = "Value", direction = "long")
   client time      Value id
1:      1    1 -0.1348442  1
2:      2    1  0.8431479  2
3:      1    2  0.6787494  1
4:      2    2 -1.3760579  2
```

I expected the following line of code to work because the documentation states that `varying` can be a matrix or single vector of names.

```
> reshape(data = dt, varying = c("Month1", "Month2"), direction = "long")
> Error in guess(varying) : 
    failed to guess time-varying variables from their names
```

This doesn't work unless I add the `v.names` argument. I don't see why adding this would help R recognize the columns in wide that correspond to a single column in long. Can someone explain? Additionally, is there a way to drop the `id` column within the `reshape()`?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think the answer is given in "If direction = "long" the varying argument can be a vector of column names (or a corresponding index). The function _will attempt to guess the v.names and times from these names_. The default is variable names like x.1, x.2, where sep = "." specifies to split at the dot and drop it from the name. To have alphabetic followed by numeric times use sep = "".", and further down "Also, _guessing is not attempted_ if v.names is given explicitly. Notice that the order of variables in varying is like x.1,y.1,x.2,y.2." ...

Comment: ... To sum up: if you provide `v.names` then reshape will treat the columns you specified in `varying` as if they contain a 'time part' in this order and the function assumes this column order: x.1,y.1,x.2,y.2 which is the case in your data. Your approach would then not work for this data `data.table(client = 1:2, Month1 = rnorm(2), year1 = 1:2, Month2 = rnorm(2), year = 3:4)`

Comment: And you can drop the id column if you specify the `idvar` argument, as in `reshape(dt, idvar = "client", varying = 2:3, v.names = "value", direction = "long")`